# SL3 dataform validation indicators don't show in tab pages

Tags: validation, silverlight-3.0, prism

I have a Prism/SL3 application with a tab control and each page of the tab control is a "Region" that has its own view and viewModel. when I want to validate the main page, I call dataForm.ValidateItem(), then I go to all the child views and do the same. the problem is, only the pages which user has clicked on them (on the tab page), get instantiated and the pages that are never shown, don't have their view instantiated, thus I can't validate them.
any help?

Answer (score -1):

I created a psuedo work around for this. It's very hacky, but it does work. My example involved walking the visual tree (up and down) to find respective controls that are invalid and then "expanding" the selected item. I have used an accordian in my example, but have also tested this with tab:
http://thoughtjelly.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/walking-the-xaml-visualtree-to-find-a-parent-of-type-t/

HTH,
Mark

**EDIT**: Link updated.

Comment: Your blog is invitation only.

Comment: Thanks for noticing :-) I've actually moved to wordpress. Please try http://thoughtjelly.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/walking-the-xaml-visualtree-to-find-a-parent-of-type-t/